# Has windows XP support multiple remote login session (RDP) at a time?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Do windows XP support multiple concurrent remote desktop sessions?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "multiple remote login", as there are several ways to read that.

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean 'multiple remote RDP sessions'? Nope. 
But some kind of 'hack' exists. It allows multiple RDP connections to XP box like Windows server terminal services, but cause violation of licence and so on...

Answer (score 2):

No - if you require a machine which can handle multiple remote RDP connections you need to purchase a server Operating System combined with Terminal services with the correct ammount of licenses for users.
Any attempt to hack/slash your Windows XP machine is not recomended for obvious reasons, not to mention as Sergey said you will have violated your License agreement with Microsoft.

Comment: Topic starter did not write anything on RDP sessions

Comment: The topic starter did not write a proper question either. It is my interpritation of what was asked.

Comment: @vgv8: Are there other "remote login sessions", besides RDP, built into Windows XP?

Comment: @vgv8 As for as I know only RDP is remote login session. I really do not know what other "remote login sessions" are available. I have no idea about remote sessions, My query is only regarding remote logins not remote sessions. If you want I can edit my question if you are not clear.

Comment: @Thangaraj, as an example, if I was to run a command on a remote machine using something like psexec that would require a remote logon to the target machine.

Comment: @Thangaraj - just so we all understand are you saying that the question is 'Can you have multiple remote desktop session's concurrently on a Windows XP workstation?'

Comment: The question was if Windows XP support (RDP or not RDP). Yes, it does support! What license is required is completely different question!

Comment: Licensing is not a completely different question. The XP license permits 1 concurrent user. This is the reason why Microsoft limits logins to one at a time (The beta, I believe, allowed 1 RDP session along with 1 console session. This was removed for licensing reasons). It doesn't matter what the OS can do if there is no way to do it that doesn't violate licenses. This is a site for professionals so any answer that involves breaking licenses is not appropriate.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, why not.

PS.

BTW, What do you mean under "remote login sessions" - opening remote desktop session? interactive logins?

When someone maps a drive latter for remote network shared resource and accesses it remotely, it also opens remote session per each user

### ----------

Update1:

I answered correctly as as far as the question was formulated and further clarified by the questioner.

It is not guessing game. There is absolutely no point in answering something what had never been formulated or asked

### ----------

Update2:

Come on! I need just one more vote to hit negative maximum amongst answers

### ----------

Update3 (Answers to answers and comments):

net sessions

shows on my Windows XP Pro SP3 (without any cracking, editing registry) 58 inbound remote sessions from 8 computers (ip-addresses) and just one utorrent shows more than 964 connections.

There is well-known 10-connections limit for Windows XP. 
Take your time to read the basics before teaching others.

### ----------

Update4

This is just ridiculous:

- 1) **instead of downvoting the questioner** who did not bother to formulate the question neither in quality noк шт quantity, the answere who write more lengthy answer is multiply downvoted
- 2) I am developer and I am "living" in "multiple remote login sessions" on Windows XP Pro. First, I even do not know which remote connections are made without establishing remote logon session.

**Even if to speak about interactive remote logins,**  should it be understood that applications like VNC Server/Viewer, TeamViewer, etc., or even  MS SQL Server Developer, etc, or **built-in MS IIS5, Server Service are illegal to run in Windows XP Pro?**

**Note: at the time of all answers the original question did not mention any RDP**

### ----------

Update5

For convenience of downvoting I shifted this discussion to [Which Windows remote connections bypass LSA? What is the definition of a login vs. logon session?](https://serverfault.com/questions/170067/which-windows-remote-connections-bypass-lsa-and-what-r-definitions-of-login-vs)

Please come to downvote there also!

---

--------- **Update6**

**@whatever-downvoted-my-answer, be it bot or human,**

May I ask why my questions were downvoted? Uncommented / unexplained, i.e. unreasonable, downvotes disservice and discredit the community of serverfault.com

My related question:
[MS licensing of multiple RDP sessions for non-MS products in Windows XP Pro](https://serverfault.com/questions/170057/ms-licensing-of-multiple-rdp-sessions-for-non-ms-products-in-windows-xp-pro), citing [Terminal Server Pro](http://goo.gl/kpEPe), allowing Windows Windows® XP to host multiple remote desktop sessions

Comment: In a case like this you should add a comment requesting clarification or further information.

Comment: no one as far as I can see said anything about the Windows XP connection limit. just because the computer can accept many inbound sessions does not mean it can accept more than one RDP connection.

Comment: Originally the starting post did not have any RDP mentioned

Comment: VNC does not open another Windows XP session, it connects you to an existing session which has been established. - For what it's worth I havent down voted you :)

Comment: BTW, don't you confuse VNC viewer with VNC server in Windows XP Pro?

Comment: I shifted this discussion to http://serverfault.com/questions/170067/which-windows-remote-connections-bypass-lsa-and-what-r-definitions-of-login-vs

Please downvote thre also!