# Which Windows remote connections bypass LSA? What is the definition of a login vs. logon session?

Tags: windows-xp, login

Having been downvoted 4 times for answering in [Has windows XP support multiple remote login session (RDP) at a time?](https://serverfault.com/questions/169149/has-windows-xp-support-multiple-remote-login-session-rdp-at-a-time/169153#169153) that Windows XP supports multiple remote login sessions (the question did not mention RDP at the time of answering). I stayed confused and intrigued:

1. What are the cases/scenarios/examples when remote connections/sessions do not require logon (though as Anonymous user) in Windows?
2. Even if to speak about remote **interactive** logins, In everyday life I use multiple remote interactive logins to IIS (web) applications, shared folders (Windows Server Service), MS SQL Server, etc.

Are not those interactive logins which create login sessions?

What are the definitions of login/logon sessions?

What are definitions of login vs. logon?

[MS licensing of multiple RDP sessions for non-MS products in Windows XP Pro](https://serverfault.com/questions/170057/ms-licensing-of-multiple-rdp-sessions-for-non-ms-products-in-windows-xp-pro)

The purpose of my questions are to avoid misunderstanding in communication with colleagues and clients but not subverting MS licensing.

Comment: I believe you have a misunderstanding of what an interactive logon is. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780095%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

RDP always requires a login; even if it's automatic. There is no way to do an "anonymous" login, they have to have some set of credentials.

An Interactive Login (as defined by MS for Windows Sessions) is one where you are presented a desktop environment that is not shared with another user (these sessions can be viewed by admin users with appropriate configuration on a terminal server, but are still owned by the user who originally logged in).

Browsing a website or accessing an SQL server is not an Interactive Login under this definition.

There is no practical difference between login and logon; assuming you mean credentials. I defined Sessions above already. If you're logged in Interactively, then you're interacting with a Session. Services which are not part of XP's base functionality may not use the same terminology, but are still limited to 10 connections at a time.